# Count Records Exept more than 'N' Consecutinve values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which have per second speed record for a vehicle. If the vehicle is stopped `speed` column will have value 0. I need to count time in movement for vehicle.

Conditions:

1. If vehicle is stopped for 3 or more seconds this will be treated as STOPPEDTIME
2. If vehicle is stopped for less than 3 seconds this will be treated as MOVEMENTTIME

I already have a cursor which calculates this value but I want to remove the use of cursor and optimize the query.

Sample Data:

```
create table Vehicle(Timer datetime,Speed int)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:01',10)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:02',14)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:03',15)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:04',14)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:05',16)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:06',0) -- do not count (3 consecutive)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:07',0) -- do not count (3 consecutive)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:08',0) -- do not count (3 consecutive)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:09',4)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:10',5)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:11',5)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:12',0)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:13',0)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:14',14)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:15',15)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:16',0)-- do not count (4 consecutive)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:17',0)-- do not count (4 consecutive)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:18',0)-- do not count (4 consecutive)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:19',0)-- do not count (4 consecutive)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:20',10)
insert into Vehicle values ('1-Jan-2015 00:00:21',12)

-- select * from Vehicle
```

**Result**

```
MOVEMENTTIME (in Seconds)
--------------------
14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5177f/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Timer) -
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Speed > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ORDER BY Timer
            )
    FROM Vehicle
),
CteCnt AS(
    SELECT RN,Speed, cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM Cte
    GROUP BY RN, Speed
)
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM CteCnt
WHERE
    Speed > 0
    OR (Speed = 0 AND cnt < 3)
```